# M2: How to give the product a "ready for shipment" duration?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I have products with a different shipping duration. How can I make it this visible on the product page. At the moment I only find a option to give the customer the information product is "in stock" or "out of stock".

How can I give the information "ready for shipment in 3/10/14 days" for each product?

Thank you

Regards

Comment: you can create an attribute for that

Answer (score 2):

You need to do customization for this. You can create attribute and can add message-text in attribute like : ready for shipment in 3/10/14 days.

One more option to create attribute with date range. On this you can customize when to display this attribute but you need to do customize for this option.

Comment: Thank you, I can create attributes, but how can I display this attribut on the position after "in stock"? like this http://img4host.net/upload/14134541594121e53686d.jpg  ("Auf Lager" means "in stock")

Comment: You will have to do customize in layout of catalog product view. Refer the SKU block and call the attribute block after this. You will also need to do CSS work for this.